# R - How to sum a variable by certain levels contained in a list of another variable?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with columns of ID, a list of other IDs, and a value. I'm looking to create a new column with the sum of the values of the IDs in the list column.

For example:

```
ID   x                Value     New Column
1    c(2,3,4)         6         17
2    c(1,3,4,7,8,9)   8
3    c(1,2)           4         14
4    c(1,3,5)         5
```

Here, we don't know the value of the new column in the second and fourth row because we don't have the data for rows 5, 7, 8, and 9. The new column for the first row is 8 + 4 + 5, or 17. There is no missing data in the actual data frame.

How can I do this for all rows in the data frame?

Thanks!

Comment: is `df$x` an actual list like `list(c(2,3,4), c(1,3,4,7,8,9))` or is it a character variable?

Comment: It is an actual list

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to maintain this kind of structure will incur significant overhead. Might I suggest a different way of structuring things?

A "values" data.frame, merely with each `id` and the `value` they possess:

```
values <- data.frame(id = 1:4, value = c(6,8,4,5))
```

Another data.frame that, for each `id`, maps which dependent-`id`s are summed into it:

```
inclusions <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3, 4,4,4),
  useid = c(2,3,4, 1,3,4,7,8,9, 1,2, 1,3,5)
)
```

From here, we just need to do a few joins to get what we need. It's handy in that you don't have to try to parse sub-data.frame lists, etc.

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(inclusions, values, by = c("useid" = "id")) %>%
  select(-useid) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(newvalue = sum(value))
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#      id newvalue
#   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1       17
# 2     2       NA
# 3     3       14
# 4     4       NA
```

Because there are some missing values in the first join, the `NA`s cause the subsequent `sum` to `NA` as well. Convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Do a bit of a lookup:

```
sapply(df$x, function(x) sum(df$Value[match(x, df$ID)]) )
#[1] 17 NA 14 NA
```

Where `df` was:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:4, x = I(list(c(2,3,4), c(1,3,4,7,8,9), c(1,2), c(1,3,5))),
  Value = c(6L, 8L, 4L, 5L))
```